# Filtering According To Second Element in a "Tuple"

Tags: perl

I am trying to zip this list with the sum of each tuple within the list, and then filter it so that only the tuples with a sum higher than 0 are in the list. At this point, using the test code given below, nothing prints after the line "---- print random tuples above 0". What am I missing?

```
 sub filter_random_4_toops_by_sum {
 my ($toops, $thresh) = @_;
 my @toops1 = ();
 @toops1 = $toops;
 my @sorted_toops = ();
 my @sortedReturn = ();
 my @filtered_toops = ();
 @sorted_toops = map{[$_, sum(@$_)]} @toops1;
 @filtered_toops = grep {$_[1]> $thresh} @sorted_toops;
 @sortedReturn = map{$_->[0]} @filtered_toops;
 return \@sortedReturn;
}
```

The Test Code:

```
sub test_step_4 {
 my($sn)= 1;
 my $toops = gen_random_4_toops(1, 100, 5);
 print "---- random 4-toops:\n";
 foreach(@{$toops}) {
print "toop $sn:\t(@{$_});\n and sum = " . sum(@{$_}) . "\n";
$sn++;
}
 my $thresh = 55;
 print "\n---- random 4-toops filtered by sum above $thresh:\n";
 my $filtered_toops = filter_random_4_toops_by_sum($toops, $thresh);
 $sn = 1;
 foreach(@{$filtered_toops}) {
print "toop $sn:\t(@{$_}); sum = ". sum(@{$_}) . "\n";
$sn++;
 }
}
```

Test code should output:

```
---- random 4-toops:
toop 1: (49 49 4 64); sum = 166
toop 2: (-2 16 57 76); sum = 147
toop 3: (-94 93 -48 85); sum = 36
toop 4: (19 -47 14 38); sum = 24
toop 5: (-57 80 -60 -35); sum = -72
---- random 4-toops filtered by sum above 0:
toop 1: (19 -47 14 38); sum = 24
toop 2: (-94 93 -48 85); sum = 36
toop 3: (49 49 4 64); sum = 166
toop 4: (-2 16 57 76); sum = 147
```

Equivalent of what I'm trying to do in Python (working):

```
def filter_random_4_toops_by_sum(toops, thresh):
    summit = 0
    s = []
    for i in toops:
        # pdb.set_trace()
        summit = 0
        for d in xrange(0,4):
            summit += i[d]
        s.append(summit)
    # pdb.set_trace()
    together = zip(toops, s)
    filtertog = [i for i in together if i[1] > 0]
    toops = [x[0] for x in filtertog]
    return toops
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@toops1` always has exactly one element.

```
@toops1 = $toops;
```

should be

```
@toops1 = @$toops;
```

But why not use `@$toops` directly instead of copying all the elements?

```
sub filter_random_4_toops_by_sum {
   my ($toops, $thresh) = @_;
   my @sorted_toops = map { [ $_, sum(@$_) ] } @$toops;
   my @filtered_toops = grep { $_[1] > $thresh } @sorted_toops;
   my @sortedReturn = map { $_->[0] } @filtered_toops;
   return \@sortedReturn;
}
```

Or even

```
sub filter_random_4_toops_by_sum {
   my ($toops, $thresh) = @_;
   return [
      map { $_->[0] }
         grep { $_[1] > $thresh }
            map { [ $_, sum(@$_) ] }
               @$toops
   ];
}
```

Or even

```
sub filter_random_4_toops_by_sum {
   my ($toops, $thresh) = @_;
   return [ grep { sum(@$_) > $thresh } @$toops ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was informative and helpful, and most importantly correct.